# KDE windows rules and no activities names in settings

Tags: kwin, kde-activities

I would like to start a few of my daily applications automatically during startup and assign them to proper activities. Currently I use 4 activities:

- Internet (Chrome),
- communication (Thunderbird and some IM),
- settings (`ksysguard`, `TeamViz` and alike) and
- terminals.

I tried to use `kwin` advanced windows rules. But unfortunately, on the `Size & position` tab, after setting Activity to `Apply initially`, I am left with two possible activities

- an empty field and
- `All activities`

Why are the names of my activities not shown?

Comment: This combobox is empty when you access windows rules by Right mouse click on window title bar -> 'More actions' -> 'Windows manager settings...'.When you get there through 'System settings' -> 'Window management' -> 'Window rules' - it's populated correctly.